# replace string if regex matched and replace with something else it matches some other regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create dict after certain conditions are met. Here is the code snippet:

```
def dic_gen(exc):
    param_errors = {re.sub(r"sss_", r"aaa_",err.name): err.address for err in exc.errors }
    param_errors["status"] = "ERROR"
    return param_errors
```

what above code is doing is that it checks if err.name have sss_ then it removes it and creates a dict. Now I also want to add another condition that if it have "ttt_" then replace it with "bbb_" Is that possible using re.sub? or what will be the most efficient way of doing that?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing `re.sub()` a function instead of replacement string you could do it like this:

```
def func(matchobj):
    return 'aaa_' if matchobj.group(0) == 'sss_' else 'bbb_'

def dic_gen(exc):
    param_errors = {re.sub(r'(sss_)|(ttt_)', func, err.name):
                       err.address for err in exc.errors}
    param_errors["status"] = "ERROR"
    return param_errors
```

Since the function is just an expression, you could make a`lambda` out of it and avoid the external function definition (although it makes the code less readable):

```
def dic_gen(exc):
    param_errors = {re.sub(r'(sss_)|(ttt_)', 
        lambda mo: 'aaa_' if mo.group(0) == 'sss_' else 'bbb_', err.name):
        err.address for err in exc.errors}
    param_errors["status"] = "ERROR"
    return param_errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you intend to do with re but I would use:

```
abc = "Something_sss whatever"
result = abc.replace("_sss","_ttt")
print result
```

Result:

```
"Something_ttt whatever"
```

Comment: what I want to do is that if there is sss_ in err.name then replace it with aaa_ and if its ttt_ then replace with bbb_ Since I am looping over the exc values, I was thinking that perhaps there is some builtin way of doing it which might be more efficient.